# PHP cURL not showing all DOM tags at review collecting

Tags: php, curl

i wanna implement a little code, that collects the reviews from the specific page  DOM.
The cURL result not full, and i don't know why, because some sub tags in the DOM is invisable in the result.
The DOM look like this in the inspector:
[image]

I try to collect the DOM with this code snippet:

```
$domain = 'feefo.com';
$page_id = 'firebrand-promotions';

$curli = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curli, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.' . $domain . '/en-US/reviews/' . $page_id . '?displayFeedbackType=SERVICE&timeFrame=YEAR'

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,* /*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'Cache-control: max-age=0',
        'Referer: https://' . $domain,
        'sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site: none',
        'sec-fetch-dest: document',
        'sec-fetch-user: ?1',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
    ]
]);

$curlResult = curl_exec($curli);
```

And what i see in the cURL result content part is this:

```
<div class="container">
    <global></global>
</div>
```

So the `<global>` tag looks empty, but it shouldn't be.
I try to extract the `<global>` tag content with the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
@$dom->loadHTML($curlResult);

$globals = $dom->getElementsByTagName('global');

$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$reviews = $xmlPath->query('//global');
```

But still i didn't see any tags in the `<global>` tag.

So can someone explain this to me, and how can it be fix this?

Big thanks in advance for your help, effort, and time. :)

Comment: Why the `@` operator? ... might be hiding potential clues. Plus, I do not see any `<global>` tags in the image, though some elements have `global` as part of the CSS names?

Comment: @Paul T. - I check your advice, but i only get: `Tag global invalid in Entity`. So sadly doesn't help me too much. Thank your for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty good chance that what you're getting in Curl is exactly what the browser gets, but the browser starts executing javascript that modify the DOM.

You can't see with with Curl, because Curl can't execute Javascript.

Comment: Sound reasonable, and looks logic. Thank you your help.
I could have thought. :)